# Increasing font size in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

On my MacbookPro, I can hold the command button down, then hit the +/= button and the fontsize increases in each and every panel, making it easier to read from a distance for my students viewing on our Smartboard.

How is this same thing performed on a PC Windows machine?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

More keys might be necessary to generate +/- (for instance, for me Zoom In is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>).

Other notes:

- You can also zoom in using the View menu
- See a list of keyboard shortcuts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (recent versions of RStudio only)

Comment: Thanks. I will check these out in one of our classroom computers today.

Comment: Super weird that the shortcut varies from what is officially documented, but I too need to hold down shift even though the menu says I just need ctr++.

Comment: thanks, only thing is my default font was so small i couldnt see the view menu

Comment: `Cmd`+`+` on MacOS.

Answer (score 6):

Tool --> Global Options --> Appearance --> Then you can adjust the font size at the right panel